# Python+Selenium [Errno 2]: No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpUgpMnz/webdriver-py-profilecopy'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, geckodriver

I am running a python script on a raspberry pi 3 with Selenium *3.14.1*, *Firefox-ESR 52.9.0*, *Python 2.7.13* and geckodriver 0.17.0. It visits a webpage clicks on a button then takes a screenshot of the page. Finally it looks for another element by its href and clicks it then stops.

The Problem is it throws me the following error right after saving the screenshot and printing "break0"  :

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpUgpMnz/webdriver-py-profilecopy'

My script is as follows:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/pi/.mozilla/firefox/8a8d2rym.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
try:
driver.get("https://www.website.com/")
time.sleep(40)
try:
    abutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/a")
    if "Claim" in abutton.text:
        abutton.click()
        print("Claim made")
except:
    print("No claims made")
driver.save_screenshot('index.png')

print("break0")
# this is where it throws the error
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href=\"/follow\"]").click()


print("break1")
time.sleep(15)
print("break2")
except:
    driver.quit()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: What if you set an absolute path instead of just a filename, like `/home/xeno/selenium_pics/index.png`?

Comment: I don't know why is this happening, but it looks like it is somehow related to FirefoxProfile...